# What is the bean scope and context holder for Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: java, spring, message-driven-bean, spring-cloud-stream

For REST call, we can use `Request-scoped` bean and `RequestContextHolder` to access the HTTP request context.

For message-driven microservices using Spring Cloud Stream, what are the equivalent **bean scope** and **context holder** that we can use to access the message context?

Comment: There is no such scope; what do you mean by "message context" ?

Comment: @GaryRussell The `message context` that I imagine is a context that only lives within the message handling span. I am looking for a way to initialize a bean when we receive a message, and destroy the bean when the message is handled.

Comment: There's no such facility; you would need a custom scope; it's probably simpler to use a `ThreadLocal`.